# Rails, select by nested items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, activerecord

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
 has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :title, :date
 belongs_to :client
end
```

How find all clients by comment date '2012-01-30'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `date` is a date type field

```
Client.joins(:comments).where(comments: { date: Date.new(2012,1,30) })
```